# Angular - Template inheritance

Tags: angular

I have the following child component and it's inheritance parent component:

```
@Component({
   template: `<p>child</p>`
})
export class EditChildComponent extends EditViewComponent{
   constructor(){
     super();
   }
}



@Component({
   template: `<p>parent</p>`
})
export class EditViewComponent{
   constructor(){
   }
}
```

Now is there any way to place the template of the EditViewComponent in the ChildComponents template like you would do with ng-content in nested components? How would I get the following result:

```
<p>parent</p>
<p>child</p>
```

Comment: Any answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Angular Doesn't provide this feature.
But you can use "Narik" to apply "UI Inheritance" in angular.

https://docs.narik.me/04.-ui-inheritance

Comment: You should make it clear that you are the author of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this in Angular. We can only inherit from classes and add their business logic to other components (classes), but this will not be done with templates as you want.

In this case, I can highlight only 2 solutions for you:

1. Create a universal component that will accept input parameters and depending on their values, you will change the template inside that component. This component will include the full role of both the parent `EditViewComponent` component and the child `EditChildComponent` component. As a result, we fully replace your two components with a single one.
2. Creating a base component (like `BaseEditComponent`) that will have the template you want to reuse and the business logic inside (if needed). You can use this component in both the child `EditChildComponent` and parent `EditViewComponent` components and pass different configurations to the input. As a result, you will have this:

`EditChildComponent`:

```
...
<app-base-edit [param1]="value1" [param2]="value2" ...></app-base-edit>
...
```

and `EditViewComponent`:

```
...
<app-base-edit [param1]="value1" [param2]="value2" ...></app-base-edit>
...
```

P.S.:
It also looks a little bit strange to use some libraries here that people recommended in the comments. In my opinion, we can have better architectural solutions and approaches for it, for example, as I described.
We're increasing the side of project bundles by using those libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Look on this article: 
[Angular 2, decorators and class inheritance](https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7)

Example:
[plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co/edit/4iYvA9JoF1VhlqyLhntU?p=preview)

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {
  Component, 
  ElementRef,
  ComponentMetadata
} from 'angular2/core';
import { isPresent } from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';

export function CustomComponent(annotation: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);

    var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
    Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
      if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
        // verify is annotation typeof function
        if(typeof annotation[key] === 'function'){
          annotation[key] = annotation[key].call(this, parentAnnotation[key]);
        }else if(
        // force override in annotation base
        !isPresent(annotation[key])
        ){
          annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
        }
      }
    });

    var metadata = new ComponentMetadata(annotation);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], target);
  }
}

@Component({
  // create seletor base for test override property
  selector: 'master',
  template: `
    <div>Parent component</div>
  `
})
export class AbstractComponent {

}

@CustomComponent({
  // override property annotation
  //selector: 'sub',
  // ANSWER: it's not possible like that but you could have a function here. Something like:
  template: (template) => { return template + 'add html to temlate in child'}
  selector: (parentSelector) => { return parentSelector + 'sub'}
})
export class SubComponent extends AbstractComponent {
  constructor() {
    //console.log(super);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  // CHECK: change view for teste components
  template: `
    <div>
      <div><sub>seletor sub not work</sub></div>
      <div><master>selector master not work</master></div>
      <div><mastersub>selector mastersub not work</mastersub></div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives [ SubComponent ]
})
export class App {

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
  }

}

bootstrap(App).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: The title states Angular 4

Comment: As you can see `import { isPresent } from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';
` this works with angular2.0.0-beta.15. I want to tag this with @Deprecated